# Hide div when user clicks browser's back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When a user clicks a thumbnail, it opens a div that covers the whole screen, and the document title and URL both change.

```
$('.view-overlay').show();
$('html,body').css("overflow","hidden");

// once AJAX is done, in success:

$('.view-overlay').append(data);
window.history.pushState('page2', title, url);
document.title = title;
```

When the user clicks the back button, I want to reverse that, with the following JS to execute:

```
$('.view-overlay').empty().append('<div class="view-close">x</div>').hide();
$('html,body').css("overflow","auto");
window.history.pushState('page1', "previous title", "previous url");
document.title = "previous title";
```

I tried `onbeforeunload` but I'm not sure if that's how it can be used

Comment: No time for a full answer at the moment, but have you seen the [`popstate` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) you detect events such as the back button being pressed.

**EDIT**: in your example, you could do:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    $('.view-overlay').empty().append('<div class="view-close">x</div>').hide();
    $('html,body').css("overflow","auto");
    window.history.pushState('page1', "previous title", "previous url");
    document.title = "previous title";
}
```

However, you don't need to manually set the title or the URL, since they were in the history stack and the browser will automatically update them.